# How do I reverse an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I've tried this code but I am unsure as to why it does not work:

```
    String[] arr = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};//AD
    String[] arr2 = arr;
    int last = arr.length-1;
    int first = 0;
    int size = arr.length;
    while (first < size) {
        arr2[first] = arr[last];
        last--;
        first++;
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: `String[] arr2 = arr;` doesn't make a copy. That's still the same array.

Comment: *"String[] arr2 = arr;"* - What Harry Potter style magic do you expect here to happen?

Comment: Just make a brand new array of the same length and fill it backwards

Comment: @tom omg I forgot this isn't python and the array changes even after you copy it....

Comment: This is also usually the sort of thing you would do with a for loop, but a while loop is just as effective

Comment: That's not correct. The arrays wouldn't change if you would ___actually___ copy them.

Comment: Python would behave the same; it has essentially equivalent assignment semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does not do what you think it does: `String[] arr2 = arr`. This is simply pointing the variable `arr2` at the same object reference as `arr`. So changes in one will show up in the other, since they're effectively the same thing.

In order to reverse an array, you need to iterate through the array and copy the *values* to your reversed array.

```
String[] arr = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
String[] reversed = new String[arr.length];

for(int i = 0, j = arr.length-1 ; i < arr.length; i++, j--) {
  reversed[j] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: You could do it in place

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer showing how to reverse an array in place into a new variable without modifying the original.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know you could do that with a for loop, so cool!

Comment: I feel like to do it in place with the same variable you would have to copy the value that you are going to be switching into a **temp** variable and then put it back.